# Открываются ненужный layout при перевороте экрана

Tags: java, android, android-layout, вёрстка

В общем есть 2 `layout`, один из них `Invisible`, другой `Visible`, но при повороте экрана оба становятся `Visible`, почему так оно становиться? Как сделать чтобы `Invisible` и `Visible` остались на месте при перевороте экрана?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должны оставаться те значения видимости, кои указаны были в разметке.

Если вы указываете эти значения программно, то вам надо сохранить в `Bundle` эти значения и при пересоздании активити вытащить их и назначить снова.